# Meteor MAIL_URL syntax for SMTP relay

Tags: meteor

Regarding [Meteor's](http://docs.meteor.com/#email) email package, is it possible to send to an SMTP mail relay that doesn't use SMTP AUTH, and if so what syntax do I use for MAIL_URL?

For example:

"bad syntax" if username:password not included:

```
smtp://mail.server.com:25/
```

"authentication failure" if given bogus values:

```
smtp://nobody@mail.server.com:25/
smtp://nobody:nopasswd@mail.server.com:25/
```

Thanks.